Know if all items in a query are registered in the database
I'm trying to query the database but I'm having difficulties.
I have a table called "items" with the following fields: id, item, active.
It contains several items.  In the active field I put the letter "S" to inform that this item is active in the system.
For example:
1, house, S 
2, table, S 
3, bed, S 
4, motorcycle, S 
5, radio 

The fifth record is not active in the system because it does not have an "S" in the active field.
And another table called "products" with the following fields (id, item1, item2, item3) with the following records:
1, house, table, motorcycle 
2, table, house, bed 
3, radio, bed, table  

I  need to search the products table as follows: I choose a record in the "items" table, for example "table".
I need to list all the records in the "products" table that contain the word "table".  So far so good, I can list it.
I'm doing it like this:
<?php        

$item = "table" 
 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE item1 LIKE '$item' OR item2 LIKE '$item' OR item3 LIKE '$item' LIMIT 10"); 
 
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
  $id = $aux["id"]; 
  $item1 = $aux["item1"]; 
  $item2 = $aux["item2"]; 
  $item3 = $aux["item3"]; 

  echo $id . " - " . $item1 . ", " . $item2 . ", " $item3 . "<br>"; 

?>

The problem is that it is listing all the records that contain the table item.  I need to check the other items and list only those records in which all records are active in the system.
In the example above it should not list record 3. because this record contains the item "radio" and this item is not active in the system.
In other words, the "radio" record in the items table does not have an "S" in the "active" column.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use prepared statements with bound parameters. See this page and this post for some good examples.

Also note two significant issues with this design. First, a LIKE query wont be able to take advantage of database indexing, so it will always do a sequential scan of every row and it will get slower as more items are added. Second, LIKE will match on partial strings, so a search for the item "tab" will also match all rows that have item "table" or "stabilizer". Both of these issues are avoid by using the many-to-many design.

Your data is denormalised. What are you going to do when a product needs to have more than 3 items? You'd have to add another column to your table and then rewrite and retest your query code to support searching another column. And searching multiple columns is not very efficient either, and having to use LIKE makes it less efficient still.
It looks like you should have a "many to many" relationship between products and items, so you need a 3rd table "Product Items" which just contains "Item ID" and "Product ID" fields, to create a proper link between each combination of product and item. Then searching through it would be much easier in SQL too.
It can also help to solve your problem, because then you'd have a clear link between the product-item entry, and the original item record, so you could easily exclude those items which aren't active, as part of the SQL WHERE clause.
Example SQL code:
CREATE TABLE `item` (id int, name varchar(50), active varchar(1) null);
CREATE TABLE `product` (id int, name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE `product_item` (productID int, itemID int);
INSERT INTO `item` (id, name, active) VALUES (1, 'house', 'S'),(2, 'table', 'S'),(3, 'bed', 'S'),(4, 'motorcycle', 'S'),(5, 'radio', null);
INSERT INTO `product` (id, name) VALUES (1, 'product A'), (2, 'product B'), (3, 'product C');
INSERT INTO `product_item` (productID, itemID) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5), (3, 3), (3, 2);

SELECT P.*, GROUP_CONCAT(I.name) AS items
FROM `product` P
INNER JOIN `product_item` PI ON P.id = PI.productID
INNER JOIN `item` I on I.id = PI.itemID
WHERE P.id NOT IN 
  (SELECT productID 
  FROM `product_item` PI 
  INNER JOIN `item` I ON I.id = PI.itemID 
  WHERE I.active IS NULL)
GROUP BY P.id, P.name

This outputs:



id
name
items




1
product A
house,table,motorcycle


2
product B
house,table,bed



Live demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/AWV7ByZ7

That's almost what I need.  But how do I list all products that contain motorcycles, for example?

Like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/cLPeoVuE

P.S. How exactly is is "almost" what you need? Is something missing? As far as I understood your question, I believe it has met the requirements you originally stated.

All products are being listed.  How do I list all products that contain the item motorcycle, for example?

I literally just told you that and gave you a demo which shows it. Look again at https://dbfiddle.uk/cLPeoVuE please

I added another WHERE clause and it worked perfectly.  But I'm having trouble putting this code into a php file.  How do I do?
SELECT P.id, P.name, GROUP_CONCAT(I.name ORDER BY I.name) AS items FROM product P JOIN product_item PI ON P.id = PI.productID JOIN item I ON I.id = PI.itemID AND I.active = 'S' WHERE P.id NOT IN ( SELECT PI.productID FROM product_item PI JOIN item I ON I.id = PI.itemID WHERE I.active IS NULL ) AND P.id IN ( SELECT PI.productID FROM product_item PI JOIN item I ON I.id = PI.itemID WHERE I.name = 'table' ) GROUP BY P.id, P.name;

mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT... etc. Just like any SQL query. How/where did you get stuck with that when you tried? "having trouble" isn't an error message.
